Caching large files to avoid frequent remote retrieval
I'm looking for some ideas or frameworks for dealing with caching large files. The goal is to avoid repeatedly calling a remote data source (rest service) to retrieve file whose size is few hundreds megabytes or even gigabytes, if possible.
One I can think of is to retrieve the file and then cache the path after the file is downloaded to the local filesystem. The next time when the file is needed, cache manager can look at the cache, return the path if the file exists and get it directly from the local filesystem with it.
Not sure if it's a feasible idea or if there is something that's more suitable to this situation.
